Div is getting extended even that it has defined width
I'm feeling pretty stupid with this question, but I spent a complete morning and couldn't really understand what happens.
Here is my component code :

export default function Summary({ activation }: SummaryProps) {
  const t = useTranslations("ActivationPage.summary");
  const tCommon = useTranslations("Common");
  const toast = useToast();
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-6 w-full overflow-x-hidden">
      <Card className="min-w-0 flex-1">
        <CardHeader className="flex flex-row items-center relative justify-between space-y-0 pb-2">
          <CardTitle className="text-sm font-medium">
            {t("activation_key")}
          </CardTitle>
          <Button
            className="absolute top-3 right-3"
            variant={"outline"}
            size={"icon"}
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              navigator.clipboard.writeText(activation.activation_key);
              toast({
                type: "info",
                message: tCommon("actions.copied"),
                id: "idCopied",
              });
            }}
          >
            <Copy className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardContent>
          <div className="text-2xl font-bold overflow-hidden text-ellipsis whitespace-nowrap">
            {activation.activation_key}
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>

      <Card className="min-w-0 flex-1">
        <CardHeader className="pb-2">
          <CardTitle className="text-sm font-medium">
            {t("machine_num")}
          </CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardContent className="flex gap-3 items-center">
          <Hash className="h-6 w-6" />
          <div className="text-2xl font-bold">{activation.machine_num}</div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <Card className="min-w-0 flex-1">
        <CardHeader className="flex flex-row items-center relative justify-between space-y-0 pb-2">
          <CardTitle className="text-sm font-medium">
            {t("host_id")}
          </CardTitle>
          <Button
            className="absolute top-3 right-3"
            variant={"outline"}
            size={"icon"}
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              navigator.clipboard.writeText(activation.host_id);
              toast({
                type: "info",
                message: tCommon("actions.copied"),
                id: "idCopied",
              });
            }}
          >
            <Copy className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardContent>
          <div className="text-2xl font-bold overflow-hidden text-ellipsis whitespace-nowrap">
            {activation.host_id}
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <Card className="min-w-0 flex-1">
        <CardHeader className="pb-2">
          <CardTitle className="text-sm font-medium">{t("end_date")}</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardContent className="flex gap-3 items-center">
          <Hash className="h-6 w-6" />
          <div className="text-2xl font-bold">{activation.machine_num}</div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

This code represent a page with some cards on headers, with quick look informations.
I want each line to be on only one line, and being truncated if it's too long.
When working with my activation_keys, everything looks fine. However, when I use the host_id (on the third card), my page is exploding width, creating a horizontal scroll, but the host_id is still truncated.
I don't understand why at some point it gets broke by the fact that a string is longer than an other one.
Here's 2 picture, the first one working, the second has the bug :


I tried many things using break-all, whitespace-nowrap, truncate, .... But none satisfied the problem.
I also tried using w-1/4 on Cards containers, but it didn't change nothing
I'm using shadcn cards (not updated them) and tailwindcss. This is a nextjs project.
EDIT :
I found a partial solution (but not the core problem). Limiting my div width with max-w-[30ch] make things work well. But I don't understand why it does. It keeps truncating the text (as exeptected) but not making the page grow.
EDIT 2 : (SOLUTION)
I found a solution using grid instead of flex. I still don't understand why it doesn't works well with flex, but it works great with a grid...

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I think the question is pretty well described, with code snippet of the component where there's not much boilerplate

I think your error appears due to flex-1 CSS. Still, it is a good practice to always set a max-width on your components just in case something weird happens.
If this does not fix your problem, try to think about flex-shrink or flex properties. Maybe you are overwriting something.

I initially used some w-1/4 and even by setting some max-w-[1920px] on parent it still got overrided

Wouldn't be better to add a max-width for the children element instead of your parent element?

I tried too, but it didn't do nothing
